# Kohana 3 routing not working properly when in the format controller/action

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3

I am new to Kohana. I am using the **default route in Kohana 3.2** which is

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'admin',
    'action'     => 'login',
));
```

**My controller** is as follows :

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Admin extends Controller{

public function __construct($request, $response) {
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
}

public function action_login(){
    $session = Session::instance();
    if($session->get('admin_id')){
        //Session is set / Logged in
        $this->request->redirect('users/list');
        exit();
    }

    if($_POST){
       $user = ORM::factory('admin');
       $post = Validation::factory($_POST)
               ->rule('username', 'not_empty')
               ->rule('password', 'not_empty');
        if(!$post->check()){
            Message::error($post->errors('admin'));
        }
        else{
            $objUserDetails = $user->checkCredentials($_POST);
            if($objUserDetails->id){
                //Valid username and password
                $session->set('admin_id', $objUserDetails->id);
                $this->request->redirect('users/list');
                exit();
            }
            else{
                Message::error("Invalid username or password");
                $this->request->redirect('admin/login');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    $this->response->body(new View(
                'login',
                array('title'=>'Administrator login')
            ));
}

public function action_logout(){
    $session = Session::instance();
    $session->delete('admin_id');
    $session->destroy();
    $this->request->redirect('admin/login');
}
```

}

**My .htaccess** is as follows :

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

When I type `http://localhost` it is working properly. But when I type `http://localhost/admin/login`  or `http://localhost/admin/logout` it is showing a 404 error.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have your `.htaccess` turned on? Try to type something wrong like "foobar" there and check if for the request you get 500 error

Comment: @zerkms I did as you told. Instead of 500 I am getting 404 error. That means mod_rewrite is disabled right ?

Comment: it means that the whole `.htaccess` is disabled. Find `AllowOverride` and set it as `All` in your `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `.htaccess` disabled, so you need to find `AllowOverride` and set it as `All` in your `httpd.conf`

Comment: Seems a lot of people are having this issue, but good to know this information has been added to the 3.3 docs: https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/develop/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls.md#404-errors

Comment: `tutorials/clean-urls` page has this information for all 3.x versions

Comment: @biakaveron documentation about this specific issue was added recently: https://github.com/kohana/core/pull/203